# java.io.StreamCorruptedException: Is there a list of Invalid code types with description?

Tags: java, ioexception

I got the exception:

```
java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid type code: 74
```

Googling didn't help me find anything related to code 74 while there are many posts related to other codes. I tried looking [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/StreamCorruptedException.html) to see if they maintain a master for all code types but without help. 
Can anybody help me with this error code or a link where I can find a master for all the code?

This error occurred during a volume testing wherein I was uploading files one by one to server for processing and other things.

Comment: To increase chances of getting correct answers consider adding [code which will let us reproduce your problem](http://sscce.org/). Also post full stacktrace   of thrown exception.

Comment: I cannot put the code or stacktrace here for security reasons. This code is working well and good for past 2 years. I'm just curious if anybody in here is familiar with `invalid type code: 74`

Comment: Your question is very vague. You really need to provide the context of when this exception happened. What method where you calling when this exception was thrown? What changed from the previous 2 years?

Comment: In all probability, the fact that this code doesn't exist is what makes it invalid. So your chances of finding things out that way are slim. And if you cannot provide code or trace, you're in the wrong place. There are no clairvoyants here.

Comment: Thanks @RealSkeptic your first line makes sense. I was performing a routine volume testing and nothing has changed in two years. I don't mean to offend any geniuses here but the way you put comments is definitely not polite. I can see that this site is full of questions a thousand times sillier than this one. And when I say thousand it's a little exaggerated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although you really did not provide much information with which one can help you, I will give you some hints where to look.

Most likely you are using a `java.io.ObjectInputStream` for reading in some data. In the source code of this class there are several places that throw such an exception with such a message:

```
throw new StreamCorruptedException(String.format("invalid type code: %02X", tc));
```

Looking at these various places I noticed that the type codes are constants in the class `java.io.ObjectStreamConstants`. The type constant "0x74" for example is declared as following:

```
final static byte TC_STRING =       (byte)0x74;
```

That maybe means that you got a string in your object input stream but you managed to read it as something else.

If you are not using an `ObjectInputStream`, then you maybe use something similar that still refers to the above mentioned constants.

Comment: Yes I'm using `ObjectOutputStream`. This answer really helped me debug although I'm yet to find the cause. I believe the VT script is flawed.

Answer (score -1):

There can't be. The question doesn't make sense. What there *is* is a list of *valid* type codes, in the Java Object Serialization Specification. Any value that doesn't appear here is invalid, by definition.

Comment: Well this is the exception that I got when I had asked the question. The app was a java applet using java net api for communication between client and server. I can't provide any more input as I'm not longer working on that project and that app is also deprecated and abandoned as far as I know.